# Can tokio::runtime be used in wasm?

Tags: multithreading, rust, webassembly, rust-tokio, wasm-pack

everybody.

```rust
let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
```

This code doesn't work when I try to build wasm.

```
let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
   |                              ^^^^^^^ could not find `Runtime` in `runtimе
```

```
let rt = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();
    |                     ^^^^^^^ private module
```

Is it possible to use tokio::runtime in wasm or do I need to look for other ways ?
Can I use multithreading ?

I tried to start an asynchronous function with rt.block_on, since the current function is not supposed to be asynchronous, it runs in a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokio does have some support WASM, see [WASM support in the docs](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/#wasm-support). You need to enable the `rt` feature (the `full` feature doesn't work and causes a compilation failure). However, it does not support multi-threaded runtime (as WASM does not support threads), and therefore does not support [`Runtime::new()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.new). You need to use [`tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.new_current_thread) and enable the features you want with the methods (which is currently only `time` and only on WASI).

However, you should reconsider if you really need `tokio`. If you are in the browser, use the browser APIs and [`wasm-bindgen-futures`](https://docs.rs/wasm-bindgen-futures) to interact with JavaScript promises via async/await. If you are on WASI, still `tokio` provides only minimal support and you may want to look for something else.